# What is the best way to parse e-mail or html template?

Tags: php, parsing, templates, preg-replace

For example I use this:

For email templates:

email.tpl:

```
hello {username}, 
your password is: {password}
```

parser.php

```
function parse(){
$message = file_get_contents("email.tpl");
$patterns[0] = "/\{username\}/";
$patterns[1] = "/\{password\}/";
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = $username;
$replacements[1] = $password;
return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);
}
```

For html templates:
html.tpl:

```
<b>hello {username}</b>, 
<p>your password is: {password}</p>
```

parser.php

```
function parse(){
$message = file_get_contents("html.tpl");
$patterns[0] = "/\{username\}/";
$patterns[1] = "/\{password\}/";
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = $username;
$replacements[1] = $password;
return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);
}
```

Is this the best way or is there a better one?

Comment: There's `str_replace` which I guess it's easier to handle than `preg_replace` (only in case you don't really need regex).
For instance , in your case `{username}` is `{username}` - no need of regex , but if you'll have `{post-234}` where 234 is an id of something - `preg_replace` would help.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is just fine, but one thing you'll find PHP folks mention frequently in passing is that 'PHP is a template engine already'.

You could therefore do something like this:

**email.tpl**

```
<?php
hello $username, 
your password is: $password
?>
```

**parser.php**

```
<?php
function parse($username, $password) {
    ob_start();
    require 'email.tpl';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

**Calling the parse function**

```
$emailBody = parse('Someuser', 'Somepass');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use preg_replace but since you're not making dynamic replacement (you only have 2 static variables called username and password), you could just use the function strtr.

`strtr` does simple string replacement

`preg_replace` does complex regexp string search and replacement

strtr will be a lot faster (if your html is heavy) .. you can use it like this :

```
function parse(){
    $message = file_get_contents("html.tpl");
    return strtr ( $message , array(
        "{username}" => $username,
        "{password}" => $password,
    ));
}
```

If you want a dynamic system (replacing automatically 0...n variables), preg_replace is the good choice